# Create PHP function with foreach loop inside

Tags: php, function, foreach

I have a foreach loop what works fine but i need to call it a few time within the same page to get different results so i thought a function would be better but i keep getting `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

heres the code that works

```
$weaponSlot = '1';

$talentGridHash =  $json2['Response']['data']['buckets']['Equippable'][''.$weaponSlot.'']['items']['0']['talentGridHash'];

$nodes = $json2['Response']['data']['buckets']['Equippable'][''.$weaponSlot.'']['items']['0']['nodes'];

foreach($nodes as $talentNode) {
// Perform operations on each nodes...

if($talentNode['isActivated'] && $talentNode['state'] === 10){
      $nodesActive[] = $talentNode;

    $perkName = $json2['Response']['definitions']['talentGrids'][''.$talentGridHash.'']['nodes'][''.$talentNode['nodeHash'].'']['steps']['0']['nodeStepName'];
    $perkIcon =  $json2['Response']['definitions']['talentGrids'][''.$talentGridHash.'']['nodes'][''.$talentNode['nodeHash'].'']['steps']['0']['icon'];

    if (strpos($perkName, 'Damage') == false) { 

$perkOutput .= '<div style="border:1px solid #999; border-radius:3px; padding:1px; float:left; margin-right:8px"><img src="http://www.example.com'.$perkIcon.'" height="22" title='.$perkName.'" /></div>'; 


    }

}

}

echo $perkOutput;
```

heres the code into a function...have i missed something??
(BTW this is the first time ive done a function, looked at examples online)

```
$perkOutput = null;
function getItemPerks($weaponSlot){

$talentGridHash =  $json2['Response']['data']['buckets']['Equippable'][''.$weaponSlot.'']['items']['0']['talentGridHash'];

$nodes = $json2['Response']['data']['buckets']['Equippable'][''.$weaponSlot.'']['items']['0']['nodes'];

foreach($nodes as $talentNode) {
// Perform operations on each nodes...

if($talentNode['isActivated'] && $talentNode['state'] === 10){
      $nodesActive[] = $talentNode;

    $perkName = $json2['Response']['definitions']['talentGrids'][''.$talentGridHash.'']['nodes'][''.$talentNode['nodeHash'].'']['steps']['0']['nodeStepName'];
    $perkIcon =  $json2['Response']['definitions']['talentGrids'][''.$talentGridHash.'']['nodes'][''.$talentNode['nodeHash'].'']['steps']['0']['icon'];

    if (strpos($perkName, 'Damage') == false) { 

$perkOutput .= '<div style="border:1px solid #999; border-radius:3px; padding:1px; float:left; margin-right:8px"><img src="http://www.example.com'.$perkIcon.'" height="22" title='.$perkName.'" /></div>'; 

    }

}

}

return $perkOutput;

}


getItemPerks(1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$json2` is not available in the function so `$nodes` is undefined.  You need to pass it in as an argument the same as `$weaponSlot`.

```
function getItemPerks($weaponSlot, $json){
    $nodes = $json //etc...
}
```

Then call: `getItemPerks(1, $json2);`

Or make a call to another function inside this one that fetches the JSON and returns an array:

```
function getItemPerks($weaponSlot){
    $json = getJSON();
    $nodes = $json //etc...
}

function getJSON(){
    $json = //get your JSON somehow
    return json_decode($json, true);
}
```

Then call: `getItemPerks(1);`

See [PHP: Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)